# Having trouble sending data through axios in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, axios

When I try to send data via axios with query data. Looks like the problem is with JSON.stringify, it returns incorrect data to be able to send.

Is there any solution to this problem?

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  query: `mutation { flowTriggerReceive(body: "{ \"trigger_id\": \"28a17088-92d7-42e7-a1f2-3594fc4b8bf9\", \"resources\": [ { \"name\": \"AppName\", \"url\": \"https://app.doman.com\" } ], \"properties\": { \"product_id\": 3665695899753, \"Rating\": 5, \"Author\": \"John Kendy\", \"Email\": \"cauhaibg@gmail.com\", \"Country Code\": \"VN\" } }") { userErrors { field, message } } }`,
  variables: {}
});
//console.log(data);
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://{shop_domain}/admin/api/2023-01/graphql.json',
  headers: { 
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Get error

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on \": \" (STRING) at [1, 51]","locations":[{"line":1,"column":51}]}]}
```

Comment: your data is not in correct json format, please convert it to json format first

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need to serialize the data object to JSON as Axios will automatically do it for you. Try to send the data object "as is" without stringify it first

```
var axios = require('axios');

var data = {
  query: `mutation { flowTriggerReceive(body: "{ \"trigger_id\": \"28a17088-92d7-42e7-a1f2-3594fc4b8bf9\", \"resources\": [ { \"name\": \"AppName\", \"url\": \"https://app.doman.com\" } ], \"properties\": { \"product_id\": 3665695899753, \"Rating\": 5, \"Author\": \"John Kendy\", \"Email\": \"cauhaibg@gmail.com\", \"Country Code\": \"VN\" } }") { userErrors { field, message } } }`,
  variables: {}
};

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://{shop_domain}/admin/api/2023-01/graphql.json',
  headers: { 
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that too but it still doesn't work. It still gives the same error as before.

Comment: Got you - it seems that you are escaping strings in your trigger without a need, worth trying to remove it `mutation { flowTriggerReceive(body: "{ "trigger_id": "28a17088-92d7-42e7-a1f2-3594fc4b8bf9", ...`